# calling datetime.strftime inside Python string.format fails

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

Why does calling datetime.strftime fails inside Python's string.format?
In an f-string it works:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

print(f'{now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}')
try:
    print('{now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}'.format(now=now))
except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)
# 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")'
```

Comment: in the f-string, you actually execute a method call (strftime of the datetime object), while string.format is not specific to datetime objects

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.vformat):

> The syntax is related to that of formatted string literals, but it is less sophisticated and, in particular, does not support arbitrary expressions.